# Get event from React JS to React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React technology.  have a mobile app developed in React Native, in that we are loading some webpages in the web view. Can we capture some events from ReactJS to React Native or can we can React Native method from React JS?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, React Native WebView exposes three different options:

- React Native -> Web: The `injectedJavaScript` prop
- React Native ->
  Web: The `injectJavaScript` method
- Web -> React Native: The
  `postMessage` method and onMessage prop

For more please read:

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native